# Use two nested for structures to log the following pattern. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
       0 1 0 1

       1 0 1 0

       0 1 0 1

       1 0 1 0
```

Any ideas on how to get this done in JavaScript using 2 nested for loops?

Comment: yes, using modulo arithmetic makes it simple

Comment: or use a nested array, each nested array holding a row.

Comment: Will it be a 1 or 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Why use specifically 2 nested for loops? This can be done in a single one.

Comment: That's the homework requirement, 2 nested for loops. If anyone knows the code and would like to share, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure, here's a very straightforward way of answering your question, assuming your tutor is wanting you to model the data first / work with a multi-dimensional array.

I suspect your question lacks a crucial detail though. What's not clear is if your assignment is trying to get you to dynamically generate that output, or get you to model a 2 dimensional array, and loop over that, or something else.

```
var x = [
    [0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0],
    [0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0],
];
var temp;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    var temp = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
        temp += x[i][j] + " ";
    }

    console.log(temp);
}
```

You could improve this code by making 2 functions, one to output the grid, essentially wrapping the loop code above into a function, which takes the grid as a parameter. A second function could be created to create a grid, with a variable amount of rows & columns.

For example, function signatures and example usage below.

```
function makeGrid (numRows, numCols) {
    // Your turn
    // Here you want to generate and return that 2-dimensional array, 
} 

function printGrid (grid) {
    // Your turn
}

// See if you can make this function.
var grid = makeGrid(4, 4);

printGrid(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take two nested `for` statements anf check if the rest value of the index with two has the same value as the other index, then take zero or one.

```js
var i, j,
    size = 4,
    temp;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    temp = '';
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        temp += (temp && ' ') + +(i % 2 !== j % 2);
    }
    console.log(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a loott!!! It's been 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Also the ternary is superflouos

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let tmp = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      if ((i+j) % 2 == 0) {
        tmp.push(0)
      } else{
        tmp.push(1);
      }
    }
    console.log(tmp.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Why down vote?? Please let me know the mistake I will fix it :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions